# UIPageViewController in Contrainer View

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to embed UIPageViewController into Container View. The ContainerView has the following layout:

[image]

It consists of UIViewController which holds Container View and 2 buttons at the bottom.

The connection between Container View and UIPageViewController is established through "embed segue".

UIPageViewController manages 3 UIViewControllers. Each UIViewController represents app walkthrough tutorial screen, and has the following layout:

[image]

The Problem: When I run the app, the first walkthrough screen looks as it is supposed to, meaning all the layout elements are displayed properly:

[image]

However, when I scroll to the next walkthrough screen only UIImageView is displayed, pushing down the other two labels, that are below it, out of the frame:

[image]

I was wondering how can the Container View display all elements of the UIViewControllers managed by UIPageViewController?

Comment: From what I understand you're giving too much unrelated information. Only give information about the view you're adding the subclasses to. Also show an image of what you expect and your current result. The 3rd and 4th image you added don't seem to belong to the same page!

Comment: 3rd Image shows what I expect, 4th image shows what I actually get. On 4th image, only UIImageView is visible, the other 2 labels are pushed down, out of the fame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by putting the contents of tutorial screen inside vertical stack view, and giving the UIImageView lesser Content Compression Resistance Priority

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set the imageView's bottom constraint to `0`. You should constrain it to the heading's top anchor. Similarly you should set the bottom of the heading to descriptions top. And set the descriptions bottom to its superview's bottom.

Comment: Doesn't seam to work. Tried as you suggested, still gives me the same thing. Could it possible have to do anything with the fact that in my  UIPageViewController I create walkthrough screen UIViewControllers in lazy property (array), where they are instantiated within the property itself, rather than viewDidLoad method? Meaning each view controller is instantiated in the background, before they even appear on the screen.

Comment: One thing to note, when I rotate the screen and rotate it back then all the UIViewControllers are displayed correctly.

Comment: You should set them inside the `viewDidLoad` the `init` method is too early and view is not yet loaded on the screen

Comment: Still they same, however, maybe it is the right direction. I have a property array orderViewControllers to store walkthrough screens, then within viewDidLoad I create 3 walkthrough screen UIViewControllers and add them to the orderedViewControllers array. However, only first one is displayed, the other 2 are still created before they are displayed. Maybe only creating the next view controller when it is scrolled to, would fix the problem, what do you reckon?